# How to log in user with Google (through Firebase) in a React app with functional components?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, oauth

I am trying to log in a user with Google in my React/Firebase app. I've followed a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umr9eNbx3ag) but the results are different. When I click the Log In button, I get redirected to Google, choose an account and then get redirected to my site.

It seems as my 'if' statement never runs, `auth.currentUser` never evaluates to true.

This is my Firebase file

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const firestore = firebase.firestore()
export const auth = firebase.auth()
export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
export const signOut = () => auth.signOut()
export default firebase
```

This is my log in component

```
import { auth, signInWithGoogle, signOut } from '../../Firebase/Firebase'

const LoginOrRegister = () => {

  const { username, setUsername, idToken, setIdToken } = useContext(Context)

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async nextUser => {
      if (auth.currentUser) {
        setIdToken(await auth.currentUser.getIdToken())
        setUsername(auth.currentUser.displayName)
      } else {
        setIdToken(null)
      }
    })
  }, [])

return (
  <div>
    <LogInForm>
    <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}> Log in with Google </button>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the console to see if there's any error output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using `signInWithRedirect` you need to make use of `auth.getRedirectResult()` instead of `auth.onAuthStateChanged` as you are actually navigating away from the app and coming back in

Below code will work or you.

```
useEffect(() => {
    auth
      .getRedirectResult()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.credential) {
          // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          setToken(token);
          // ...
        }
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
        setData(user);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
        // ...
      });
  }, []);
```

You can find the reference **[documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)**

Comment: I am thinking there's something else wrong as the if doesn't run. the error code an error message get logged onto the screen, "auth/timeout The operation has timed out."

Comment: There's also a new error coming on the console, 

Uncaught Error: Network Error
    at auth.esm.js:257
    at e.b (auth.esm.js:73)
    at Nc (auth.esm.js:76)
    at Jc (auth.esm.js:76)
    at D.push../node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js.k.ec (auth.esm.js:75)
    at sc (auth.esm.js:69)

Comment: Yes! The sign in will at time work and at times not. When it doesn't work, I'll get either the network error above or the 'auth/timeout The operation has timed out' error

Comment: Will check it out to see if I can reproduce the issue you are facing. When I tried a demo of it on my local, I didn't face any such errors. Will update in a comment if I find anything on it